# How to call facebook sync from another plugin - Wordpress - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook-for-woocommerce/

Hello, I have a plugin that updates the price via ajax.
From what I saw the facebook plugin only syncs if you hit the update button on the product page.

Therefore, when my other plugin updates the price by ajax, the changes are not reflected in the facebook synchronization.

My question is how to call the update manually through another plugin.
Is there a trigger to call the sync function?

I need to call sync when the ajax response ends in exactly this code.

```
                $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : ajaxurl,
                data : {
                action: 'updatenotasexterpronedu',
                notasadmin : notasadmin,
                product_id: <?php echo $post->ID; ?>,
                execute: "addnotes" //otroidenficiador
                },
                success: function(response) {

               **//// I need to call the product synchronization here ///**
               **//// I need to call the product synchronization here ///**
               **//// I need to call the product synchronization here ///**

                if (response == "Okeytodo") {
                alert ("Nota de Producto y precio Externo actualizada");
                }
                else {
                alert ("Error de respuestas, Nota y precio de Producto Externo no actualizada");
                }
                }
            });
```

Thanks

Comment: How about this hook ? wp_update_post() - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/

Comment: Check this light weight [Facebook for woocommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/webtoffee-product-feed/) plugin

Comment: From a quick scan on the plugin i found those create_or_update_product_set_item() and function ajax_sync_all_fb_products() in facebook-commerce.php